# Regexp for check that string contains mixed characters: 0-n digits and 0-m letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to find regular expression which allows me to pass string which has 0-n digits and 0-m lower-case letters where **the letters and digits can be mixed**. Any other characters are not allowed. As far I have this and don't have idea how make "mixing" work

```js
// example n and m values and array with input strings to test
let n=2,m=3; 
let s=["32abc","abc32","a3b2c","3abc2","a2","abcd23","a2b3c4","aa","32","a3b_2c"];

let r=s.map(x=>/[0-9]{2}[a-z]{3}/.test(x));

console.log("curr:", JSON.stringify(r));
console.log("shoud be:   [true,true,true,true,true,false,false,true,true,false]");
```

Comment: I think you want `1` to `n`/`m` repetitions. Are you sure of the expected results? Try `new RegExp("^(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){1," + n + "})(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){1," + m + "})")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I update question

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to achieve with a single regex:

```js
let n=2,m=3; 
let s=["32abc","abc32","a3b2c","3abc2","a2","abcd23","a2b3c4","aa","32", "a3b_2c"];
let rx = new RegExp(
    "^" +                                         // Start of string
    "(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){0," + n + "}[^0-9]*$)" + // only 0 to n digits
    "(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){0," + m + "}[^a-z]*$)" + // only 0 to m letters
    "[a-z0-9]*" +                                 // only allow 0 or more letters/digits
    "$"                                           // End of string
);
let r=s.map(x=> rx.test(x));

console.log("current is:", JSON.stringify(r));
console.log("shoud be:   [true,true,true,true,true,false,false,true,true,false]");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lxYTcX/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){0,2}[^0-9]*$)`  - a positive lookahead that requires, immediately to the right of the current location, that there are zero to two occurrences of any 0+ chars other than digits and then a digit, and then 0+ chars other than digits to the end of the string
- `(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){0,3}[^a-z]*$)` - a positive lookahead that requires, immediately to the right of the current location, that there are zero to two occurrences of any 0+ chars other than lowercase ASCII letters and then a digit, and then 0+ chars other than lowercase ASCII letters to the end of the string
- `[a-z0-9]*` - 0 or more lowercase ASCII letters or digits
- `$` - end of string

Comment: the one problem with this solution is that string like `a3b_2c` is valid

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski I wrote before: *NOTE: If you only want to match strings consisting of letters and digits, add `[a-z0-9]*$` at the end of the regex pattern*. Modified to only match those strings.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 4):

Rather than a single RE, consider testing both letters and numbers separately, with a global flag, and check whether the length of the global match array is `n` and `m` respectively:

```js
let n = 2,
  m = 3; // example n and m values
let s = ["32abc", "abc32", "a3b2c", "3abc2", "a2", "abcd23", "a2b3c4", "aa", "32"];


let r = s.map(str => (
  /^[0-9a-z]*$/.test(str) &&
  (str.match(/[0-9]/g) || []).length <= n &&
  (str.match(/[a-z]/g) || []).length <= m
));
console.log("current is:", JSON.stringify(r));
console.log("shoud be:   [true,true,true,true,true,false,false,true,true]");
```

Or, to be more wordy but perhaps more elegant, without creating an empty intermediate array:

```js
let n = 2,
  m = 3; // example n and m values
let s = ["32abc", "abc32", "a3b2c", "3abc2", "a2", "abcd23", "a2b3c4", "aa", "32"];


let r = s.map((str, i) => {
  const numMatch = str.match(/[0-9]/g);
  const numMatchInt = numMatch ? numMatch.length : 0;
  const alphaMatch = str.match(/[a-z]/g);
  const alphaMatchInt = alphaMatch ? alphaMatch.length : 0;
  return numMatchInt <= n && alphaMatchInt <= m && /^[0-9a-z]*$/.test(str);
});
console.log("current is:", JSON.stringify(r));
console.log("shoud be:   [true,true,true,true,true,false,false,true,true]");
```

Comment: I think OP means *at most* `n` digits and `m` lower case letters.

Comment: Perfect and neat +1

Comment: the one problem with this solution is that it match string "32_bc" - other caraters than digits and low leters are not allowed

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski You can add one more alternation with [^a-z0-9]

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Add another test then, like `/^[0-9a-z]*$/.test(str)`

Comment: Thank you for your effort - I already give +1 to you answer, but accept pure regexp solution which is more I looking for